# Rails: rescue a after_commit callback method if failed and carry on with executing other methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

```
class A
    after_commit :a, :b, :c, :d, :e, on: [:create, :update]

    def a
    end

    def b
    end

    def c
    end

    def d
    end

    def e
    end

end
```

Now the after_commit will execute e, d, c, b, a in order.

Is there any way to skip a method if it raise some error/exception so that other callback filters will get attempted even if the methods executed before it fails.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you already use regular ol' exception handling in there via `begin; rescue`?

Comment: In the real code, there are many methods in the callback. Just wanted to know if there is any simple hack to do the same, instead of adding begin; rescue inside each method.

Answer (score 0):

You can [rescue](http://blog.honeybadger.io/a-beginner-s-guide-to-exceptions-in-ruby/) any errors:

```
class A
  after_commit :a, :b, on: [:create, :update]

  def a
    # ...
  rescue StandardError
    # no-op
  end

  def b
    # ...
  rescue StandardError
    # no-op
  end
end
```